# Need to print JSON result in PHP

Tags: php, json, curl

Here i need to print the json like output coming from CURL.

This is the output

```
{"call_id":"df0213a216b2af6767955e4052fb084b","to":"XXXXXXXX","status":"0","error_text":"Success"}
```

like call_id value, To value and status value

Here my coding and i have tried few method too

```
$phoneno = "Test";

$fields = array('api_key' => 'XXXXX',
            'api_secret' => 'XXXX',
            'to' => 'XXX',
            'from' => 'XXXX',
            'text' => $phoneno);


 $url = 'https://api.nexmo.com/tts/json?' .http_build_query($fields, '', "&");

$ch = curl_init($url);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);
$response = curl_exec($ch);
print_r($response);

$json_output = json_decode($response, true);  

echo "Trying to print ### ".$text = $json_output[0]->call_id;     


foreach ($json_output as $trend){         
 echo $trend['call_id']."\n";   
 echo $trend['status']."\n"; 
 echo $trend['error_text']."\n";   
}
```

Any idea how to take it. ??

Comment: print like output from curl? then don't decode, just `echo $response`?

Comment: well $response will print the whole output. I need to separate the call_id , Status and error_text parameter value separately..

Comment: `echo $json_output['call_id'];`

Comment: Do you receive an array of objects from the curl request or only one object?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This should work...

```
 echo $json_output['call_id']."\n";   
 echo $json_output['status']."\n";
 echo $json_output['error_text']."\n";
```